# CodeIgniter: tips for using templates

Tags: templates, codeigniter

Just started using Codeigniter (yesterday) and am wondering what templating features people are using?

Is it possible to create a view and just load it whenerever necessary?

Thanks,

Jonesy

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957000/what-codeigniter-template-library-is-best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of templating is to create a shared layout with a common header. footer etc and then just have a "body" that changes per-page.

At the most basic level you can just include header and footer inside each of your views like this:

> load->view('header'); ?>
>
> This is my page.
>
> load->view('footer'); ?>

That can be fine but start building an application of any real size and you'll find problems.

There are million ways of doing templating, but the way I have used for years is this [Template library](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/). It's seen me through 20-30 projects varying projects and is used by many so you know it's tried and tested.

Comment: page link is going to a 404. actual link: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a view and just load it whenerever necessary?

Yes. This is the typical behavior of the MVC structure, not just in CI. Your views are presentation layers that should be mostly devoid of logic/processing.

Comment: So say I had a view called header I can just load header within another view?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's generally how it's done. Basically use <?php include("header.php"); ?> in your views. The view is the same thing as a standard PHP file with the exception of the fact that you never access them directly. :)

Comment: @iamjonesy: No, you shouldn't have to use the `include` syntax in your views. If you want to load a view within another view, use CodeIgniter's view loader: `$this->load->view('header')`.

Comment: True, yes. That is likely better; it keeps logic/calls within the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is the following.

In your controller, load your template like so

```
$template_data = array('contains', 'data', 'for', 'template',
                       'while', 'the', 'specific' => array('may', 'contain',
                       'data', 'for', 'the', 'view_file'));
$this->load->view('template/needed.php');
```

In your template, you now have the `$template_data` array to populate it [if need be!]. You may now load the specific view like so

```
<div id="yield">
  <?php echo $this->view('specific/viewer.php', $template_data['specific']); ?>
</div>
```

**Note:**

1. The `template/needed.php` should be in the `application/views` folder.
2. The `specific/viewer.php` file should also be in your `views` directory (i.e. the path to this file should be something like `WEB_ROOT/application/views/specific/viewer.php`)

The beauty of this is that any view file could be used as a template if need be.