# how to get html from method in controller of codeigniter and echo to layout?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, layout

I have a layout file and many controller for every job.

```
------------------------------
|   {menuController/index}    |
|                             |
-------------------------------
| {slideshowController/index} |
-------------------------------
|  {footerController/index}   |
-------------------------------
```

`postController/index` for show all post into home page.

`menuController/index` for show menu into top of home page.

... `footerController`,`slideshowController` and so on.

I will use same

```
{{postController/index}}
{{menuController/index}}
{{footerController/index}}
```

Inject to Html of Layout.php file.

```
footerController/index
```

that's call index function of `footerController` so return Html of View related to it.

I put in the Layout where appropriate.
How do I do this?

Do you have another solution?

Comment: May be it can help you, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7942502/6315304)

Comment: If I can call method on another controller .it's will work for me.thanks.

Comment: @hamedhossani can you explain bit more. Add your controller code and few codes of respective views ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->load->library('../controllers/myothercontroller');
```

Then do this:

```
echo( $this->myothercontroller->function_name() );
```

that's answer me.

in `function_name()`

```
return  $this->ci->load->view ('myothercontroller/view',array ( 'item' => $items ),true);
```

Comment: USE HMVC if you need to load controllers with in controllers. Normal MVC cannot do it.

Answer (score 1):

By using view method you can echo html content.

```
 <?php
         $data = $this->load->view('view_file', true) ;
  ?>
```

Comment: yes.i echo html in footerController/index method.for example.i process on my data.this is'nt my answer.thanks.